# Apply a animation to an HTML Tag with Javascript on Clickevent

Tags: javascript, html, sass

:D

I got akey frame and i want to apply the animation it to the body when button is clicked

```
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', infos2)
function infos2 () {


document.getElementsByTagName("body").style = "body{animation:rotate-scale-up .2s linear infinite both}";
}
```

well my JS dosent work obviously :D Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The problem here is that the style you apply here is invalid.
Your style should be applied like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.animation = "rotate-scale-up .2s linear infinite both";
```

*getElementsByTagName* returns an array of objects, therefore you have to insert [0] to select the first element in that array to make it work correctly.
You can also use *document.body* instead.

If you apply a style directly on a HtmlObject like the body, the style will expicitly be set on this element. You don't need a 'body' selector in this case.

Plus: You need an imported stylesheet or a style tag in the page, where the animation-keyframes of rotate-scale-up are defined. It's not obvious if you already done that or not.
Something like:

```
<style>
    @keyframes rotate-scale-up{
      0% {   transform: scale(.1) rotate(0deg)}
      100% { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg)}
    }
</style>
```

Otherwise you page will not know what rotate-scale-up is.

Comment: thanks very much. yes i have the keyframe in an external style.css :)